# Extract text between tags with XPath including markup

Tags: python, xpath

I have the following piece of XML:

```
...<span class="st">In Tim <em>Power</em>: Politieman...</span>...
```

I want to extract the part between the `<span>` tags.
For this I use XPath:

```
   /span[@class="st"]
```

This however will extract everything including the `<span>`.
and.

```
  /span[@class="st"]/text()
```

will return a list of two text elements. One containing "In Tim". The other ":Politieman". The `<em>..</em>` is not included and is handled like a separator.

Is there a pure XPath solution which returns:

```
In Tim <em>Power</em>: Politieman...
```

**EDIT**
Thanks to @helderdarocha and @TextGeek. Seems non trivial to extract plain text with XPath only including the `<em>`.

The /span[@class="st"]/node() solution creates a list containing the individual lines, from which it is trivial in Python to create a String.

Comment: Do you want the string you typed, or a tree fragment that includes an "em" element and 3 text nodes?

Comment: @TextGeek: I want the string.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To get *any* child node you can use:

```
/span[@class="st"]/node()
```

This will return:

1. Two child text nodes
2. The full `<em>` node (element and contents).

If you actually want all the `text()` nodes, including the ones inside `em`, then get all the `text()` descendants:

```
/span[@class="st"]//text()
```

or

```
/span[@class="st"]/descendant::text()
```

This will return three text nodes, the text *inside* `<em>`, but not the `<em>` elements.

Comment: Thanks. Your first option is the best since it will not eat the <em>. However I still need to construct the text from the list. Which is possible, but not pure XPath.

Comment: What output do you expect? You can also concatenate (with `concat(...)`) the text nodes in XPath and return a single string with all the text.

Comment: As said in the original question. I want this:   "In Tim <em>Power</em>: Politieman..." As a string.   BTW your first solution with the /node() I can easily do this by concatenating from a Python list. Not pure XPath, but still great.

Comment: You want a *string* containing XML tags? This *is* possible in pure XPath but a general solution won't be trivial. It's easier in XPath 2.0 or 3.0 using `string-join`), but it will probably be more efficient to deal with that in your host language. If you just had to generate that *one* string or want to do something with the *node* positions you can use something like: `concat(//span/node()[1], '<',name(//span/node()[2]),'>', //span/node()[2], '</',name(//span/node()[2]),'>', //span/node()[3])` (but it's obviously not a general solution, as it applies only to your example)

Comment: Thx @helderarocha. Your previous /node() solution helps. The concat solution works when having a fixed list length. Will edit my question

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like you want the equivalent of the Javascript DOM innerHTML() function, but for XML. I don't think there's a way to do that in pure XPath.

XPath doesn't really operate on markup strings like "<em>" and  "</em>" at all -- it works with a tree of Node objects (there might possibly be an XPath implementation that tries to work directly off markup, but I doubt it). Most XPath implementations wouldn't even have the 4 characters "<em>" anywhere (except maybe kept around for printing error messages or something), and of course the DOM could have been built from scratch rather than from XML or other input in the first place. Likewise, XPath doesn't really figure on handing back marked-up strings, but lists of nodes.

In XSLT or XQuery you can do this easily, but not in XPath by itself, unless I'm missing something.

-s